# C++ SYSENTER x86 calls in inline assembly

Tags: c++, windows, assembly, x86, sysenter

I'm about to learning how sysenter on x86 works. and i created a simple console application on x86 platform, which should call the NtWriteVirtualMemory function manually in inline assembly.

i started with this code here, but it seems that the compiler dont understand the opcode "sysenter" so i decided to `_emit` them with the bytes for sysenter.(maybe i need to change something in my project settings?) it compiles but when its about to calling the function visual studio gives me an error that my `ret` is an illegal instruction while executing, and the program stops.

someone have knowledge how to do that correctly?

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>



__declspec(naked) void __KiFastSystemCall()
{
    __asm
    {
        mov edx, esp

        // need to emit "sysenter" because of syntaxerrors, "Opcode"; "newline"
        _emit 0x0F
        _emit 0x34
        
        ret // illegal instructiona after execute?

    }

}

void Test_NtWriteVirtualMemory(HANDLE hProcess, PVOID BaseAddress, PVOID Buffer, SIZE_T sizeToWrite, SIZE_T* NumberOfBytesWritten)
{
    __asm
    {
        push NumberOfBytesWritten
        push sizeToWrite
        push Buffer
        push BaseAddress
        push hProcess

        mov eax, 0x3A // Syscall ID NtWriteVirtualMemory in Windows10


        mov edx, __KiFastSystemCall
        call edx

        add esp, 0x14 // 5 push *  4 bytes 20 dec

        retn
    }
}

void Test_NtWriteVirtualMemory(HANDLE hProcess, PVOID BaseAddress, PVOID Buffer, SIZE_T sizeToWrite, SIZE_T* NumberOfBytesWritten)
{
    __asm
    {
        push NumberOfBytesWritten
        push sizeToWrite
        push Buffer
        push BaseAddress
        push hProcess


        mov eax, 0x3a // Syscall ID NtWriteVirtualMemory in Windows10
        mov edx, 0x76F88E00
        call edx
        ret 0x14
    }
}



int main()
{
    std::cout << "Test Hello World\n";

    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, GetProcessId("MyGame.exe"));
    if (hProcess == NULL)
        return false;

    DWORD TestAddress = 0x87A0B4; // harcoded
    DWORD TestValue = 4;
    Test_NtWriteVirtualMemory(hProcess, (PVOID)TestAddress, (PVOID)TestValue, sizeof(DWORD), NULL);


    CloseHandle(hProcess);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The Windows syscall numbers can change depending on what patch level the machine is on. Please don't do this.

Comment: yes, i know its just for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making system calls in x86 Windows is different from x64. You need to specify the correct arguments length in *ret* otherwise you will get illegal instruction and/or runtime esp.

Furthermore I don't recommend you to use inline assembly, instead use it inside an .asm file or as shellcode.

To make a **correct** x86 system call on x86 Windows:

```
mov eax, SYSCALL_INDEX
call sysentry
ret ARGUMENTS_LENGTH_SIZE
mov edx,esp
sysenter
retn
```

To make a **correct** x64 system call on x64 Windows:

```
mov eax, SYSCALL_INDEX
mov r10,rcx
syscall
retn
```

The above will work 100% correctly on any x86 and x64 Windows (tested). Can't help you with inline assembly though, because I never used it that way.

Enjoy.

Answer (score 4):

Do you have a 32-bit **only** version of Windows?

`sysenter` was the "successor" of `int 2eh` and introduced during the Windows XP era.
The 64-bit versions of Windows don't use it, in fact it **was removed** since:

1. `sysenter` and `sysret` are illegal in long mode in an AMD CPU (irrespective of the compatibility mode).
2. The `IA32_SYSENTER_CS` MSR is left to zero by a 64-bit version of Windows<sup>1</sup>.
   This will cause a #GP fault when executing `sysenter`.
   If you single-step through your `__KiFastSystemCall` you should see the debugger catch an exception with code *0xc0000005* when executing `sysenter`.

So, in order to use `sysenter` you must have a real 32-bit version of Windows.
Running a 32-bit program on a 64-bit version of Windows won't work, that's compatibility mode (done through the WOW64 machinery).
If, besides having a 64-bit version of Windows, you also have an AMD CPU then it won't work double time.

---

Windows 64-bit uses `syscall` for 64-bit program or an indirect call to the `WOW32Reserved` field of the *TEB*<sup>2</sup>, you should use those.
Beware that the 64-bit system call convention is slightly different from the usual one: particularly it assumes the `syscall` is in a *function of its own*, thus it expects the parameters on the stack to be shifted up by 8.
Plus, the first parameter must be in `r10`, not `rcx`.

For example, if you inline the `syscall` instruction, the first parameter on the stack (if any) must be at `rsp + 28h` and not at `rsp + 20h`.

The 32-bit compatibility mode syscall convention is also different, you need to set both `eax` and `ecx` to specific values.
I didn't dig what exactly `ecx` is used for but it may be related to an optimization called [`Turbo thunks`](https://wbenny.github.io/2018/11/04/wow64-internals.html) and must be set to a specific value.
Note that while syscall numbers are very volatile, turbo thunks are even more because they can be disabled by the admin.

---

<sup>1</sup>I don't have a definitive source for this, it is just zero on *my* version of Windows and it makes `sysenter` fault.

<sup>2</sup>I.e. a `call DWORD [fs:0c0h]`, this will point to a code that will jump to a gate descriptor for a 64-bit code segment that in turn will execute a `syscall`

Comment: my windows is a 64 bit version, my console is 32 bit and my game is too 32bit. i tried to replace ```call edx``` with the ```call dword ptr fs : [0xC0]```. it runs but gaves me an access violation on function call..

Comment: Take your 32-bit version of *ntdll.dll* and disassemble `NtWriteVirtualMemory`, you should see what values to put in **all the registers** that are needed (this includes `edx`, `eax` and `ecx`, depends on the version of Windows).

Comment: thanks i did that, heres a picture of the bytes [link]https://imgur.com/a/V6FV1A8. i make all this assembly similar, but it doesnt really compile -> "access violation". i added the code above i used.

Comment: you didn't push the return address, `NtWriteVirtualMemory` has the caller return address at the top of the stack when entered. Also, I'm not sure hardcoding an address will work for all the runs (I don't know if Windows does ASLR on 32-bit binaries). If I were you, I'd make a simple program that calls `NtWriteVirtualMemory` normally and then step through it while stepping through the faulting program, checking the stack and register values. This would highlight any discrepancies.

Answer (score 1):

Since you got illegal instruction on the ret instruction rather than the sysenter instruction, you know the sysenter instruction was decoded correctly by the CPU. Your call got into kernel mode, but the kernel didn't like your system call invocation.

Probably it was depending on user-space to help save some registers because `sysenter` is very minimal.  Check the stack pointer after returning from the kernel as you single-step before letting `ret` execute.

I'd be only speculating as the the problem, but wrapping the syscall gate in another function call looks wrong to my eyes. As I said in comments, do not do this because the syscall numbers can change on you.

Under Linux, 32-bit processes call through the VDSO (a library injected into their address space by the kernel) to get the optimal system-call instruction, used in a way that matches what the kernel wants.  (`sysenter` doesn't preserve the stack pointer so user-space has to help.)

Perhaps if you want to play with this instruction you're better off writing a toy OS.

Sorry it's not a ton of answer, but it's not completely unreasonable.

Comment: thanks for the information, but who can show me how to do it correctly then??

Comment: x86-64 GNU/Linux has glibc use `syscall` directly, only indirecting via the VDSO for "system calls" that don't need to enter the kernel.  (`getpid`, `clock_gettime`, etc.)  32-bit x86 glibc does indirect via the VDSO for everything to let the kernel's "library" do the optimal user-space side of the sysenter dance, or use 32-bit `syscall` on old AMD, or use `int 0x80`.  https://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2016/04/05/the-definitive-guide-to-linux-system-calls/  So I think you reversed "x86" and "x64" in your 3rd paragraph.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Feel free to edit. It's a doomed answer anyway as OP only wants a Windows answer.